# Adding text to field with FieldAppendText

Tags: lotusscript

I'm trying to add text to a text field using .FieldAppendText on a button click.

Code in the button click event:

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
    Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
    Set uidoc = workspace.CurrentDocument
    Call uidoc.FieldAppendText _
    ( "testejam", "kappa" )
End Sub
```

When button is clicked, text is added to the field, but the problem is that the added text doesn't appear in a new line but i've set the text field properties "Separate values when user enters"- "New line" and "Display separate values with"- "New line". I don't see where's the problem and why the text is not added to a new line each time a press the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add new line yourself with `Chr(10)`:

```
Call uidoc.FieldAppendText("testejam", Chr(10) + "kappa")
```

The other options you mentioned only work if you add a new list element to field.

Answer (score 4):

If you really just want to add a new line to a textfield WITHOUT having multiple values, then the solution of Kurt is the correct one (although I would use `Chr$(13) + Chr$(10)` on a windows pc to have the same as manually pressing the enter key).

But if you want to have "multiple values" in your field, then the Knuts answer only works, if your Field has "New Line" as separator set.

If you change that or want to use this code more "universally", then use the backend- document and AppendToTextList- method of NotesItem Class to do this change:

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
    Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
    Dim doc as NotesDocument
    Dim item as NotesItem
    Set uidoc = workspace.CurrentDocument
    Set doc = uidoc.Document
    Set item = doc.GetFirstitem( "testejam" )
    Call item.AppendToTextList( "kappa" )
End Sub
```

It might be, that you need a `Call Source.Refresh` as last line to make the changes visible.

This approach is independent of the used field separator in the field "testejam".

In addition this code also works, if "testejam" is a computed field. The uidoc solution will fail for computed fields.

Comment: The question was not about adding an element to a text list. The goal was to append text to a field and separate it from existing content by a new line.

Comment: I understand your point and probably that was, what the OP meant. But: Setting the field properties to "Display Separate Lines with New Lines" means: The field is multi value. And adding a value with a Newline in the frontend is technically completely different from setting it in the backend. The result will be different: In the frontend the property will cause the field to contain 2 values. In the backend the field will contain ONE value containing a Newline as long as you don't ComputeWithForm or open the document in frontend and save...